# f#: encoding even and odd in (inductive) types?

Tags: types, f#, type-theory

I've been reading [Practical Foundations for Programming Languages](https://books.google.com/books?id=9sshAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA16&ots=bGdpXiYQIH&dq=simultaneous%20inductive%20definition%20even%20odd&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false) and found the Iterated and Simultaneous Inductive definitions interesting. I was able to pretty easily encode a mutually recursive version of even and odd functions I found [online](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/introsml/core/recfns.htm).

```
let rec even = function
| 0 -> true
| n -> odd(n-1)
and odd = function
  | 0 -> false
  | n -> even(n-1)

printfn "%i is even? %b" 2 (even 2)
printfn "%i is odd? %b" 2 (odd 2)
```

But it's less clear to me (I am an F# newb) if I can do this at the type level rather than via a function. I've seen implementations of Peano numbers in F# so I feel like this should be possible.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that going into dependent types territory is going to be nasty and ugly (parts of Scala's `shapeless` leave me both scared and in awe), but probably can be done with some black-magic and hackery :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the black-magic:

```
type Yes = Yes
type No  = No

type Zero = Zero with
    static member (!!) Zero = Yes    
    static member (!.) Zero = No

type Succ<'a> = Succ of 'a with
    static member inline (!!) (Succ a) = !. a
    static member inline (!.) (Succ a) = !! a

let inline isEven x = !! x
let inline isOdd  x = !. x
```

Based on [this implementation of Peano numbers](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/blog/2011/10/27/type-level-programming/) and using operators to avoid writing constraints by hand, `!.` stands for odd and `!!` for even.

```
// Test
let N1 = Succ Zero
let N2 = Succ N1
let N3 = Succ N2
let N4 = Succ N3

isOdd N3       // val it : Yes = Yes
isEven N3      // val it : No = No

// Test at type-level
let inline doSomeOddStuff (x: ^t when ^t : (static member (!.) : ^t -> Yes)) =        
    ()

let x = doSomeOddStuff N3
let y = doSomeOddStuff N4   // Doesn't compile
```

I use operators in order to show how easy is to go from the value-level solution to the type-level solution. Then you can go ahead and write the same with static constraints, for completeness here's that version:

```
type Zero = Zero with
    static member Even Zero = Yes
    static member Odd  Zero = No

type Succ<'a> = Succ of 'a with
    static member inline Even (Succ a) : ^r = (^t : (static member Odd  : ^t -> ^r) a)
    static member inline Odd  (Succ a) : ^r = (^t : (static member Even : ^t -> ^r) a)

let inline isEven x : ^r = (^t : (static member Even : ^t -> ^r) x)
let inline isOdd  x : ^r = (^t : (static member Odd  : ^t -> ^r) x)
```

It's more verbose but reads better at intellisense, for instance the constrained function will read:

```
 val inline doSomeOddStuff :
   x: ^t -> unit when  ^t : (static member Odd :  ^t -> Yes)
```

**UPDATE**

Here's an alternative solution which might be closer to what you have in mind:

```
type Parity =
    | Even
    | Odd

type Even = Even with static member (!!) Even = Parity.Even   
type Odd  = Odd  with static member (!!) Odd  = Parity.Odd

type Zero = Zero with
    static member (!!) Zero = Even

type Succ<'a> = Succ of 'a with
    static member inline (!!) (Succ (Succ a)) = !! a
    static member        (!!) (Succ Zero)     = Odd

let inline getParity x = !! x
let inline getParityAsValue x = !! (getParity x)

// Test
let N1 = Succ Zero
let N2 = Succ N1
let N3 = Succ N2
let N4 = Succ N3

getParity N3        // val it : Yes = Yes
getParity N4        // val it : No = No
getParityAsValue N3 // val it : Parity = Odd
getParityAsValue N4 // val it : Parity = Even

// Test at type-level
let inline doSomeOddStuff (x: ^t when ^t : (static member (!!) : ^t -> Odd)) =        
    ()

let x = doSomeOddStuff N3
let y = doSomeOddStuff N4   // Doesn't compile
```

So here you can get the result as a type and also the DU value from that type.

Comment: Very cool! Any reason you went with `Yes`/`No` rather than naming those types `Even`/`Odd`? I was really envisioning something more like John Palmer's below answer, where even and odd are types themselves, rather than methods on Peano number types. If that's possible, is it possible to combine the Even and Odd types in a discriminated union, like `Parity`? (A sort of mirror of `True`/`False` in `Boolean`...)

Comment: Normally I use ``Yes`` and ``No`` as the type level Boolean, I'm not sure if there is a sort of convention because I've seen it before. You can rename them to ``Even`` and ``Odd`` but that's less general. Regarding the DU note that if you make them part of a single DU they would have the same type, so no type level discrimination will happen.

Comment: See the update. I think it's closer to what you're looking for. There you have both the type level and the DU value level. Note that is always possible to get a (run-time) value from a (compile-time) type. The opposite is not true.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite an ideal setup as their are two separate encodings for `succ` but it has got the basic idea of how it could work:

```
type Even=
|Zero
|Succ of Odd
and Odd = |Succ_ of Even
```

Comment: This is actually exactly the direction I started in. Though I went with `EvenPlusOne` and `OddPlusOne` instead of two different `Succ`. Can you flesh out a little more?